# How to move a window taller than the screen to access the bottom?

Tags: mac, osx-mountain-lion, iphoto

I am running OS X Mountain Lion. I have an application called iPhoto Library Manager that spit out an error long enough to take up more than the screen. The continue button is at the bottom of the window, but I can't move the window up above the menu bar, so I can't access the 'continue' button.

I'm in the middle of a very large merge and don't want to lose it by quitting and relaunching the app. Also, because it's an error window, I don't have access to any of the menu bar options.

There has to be a way to move the window above the menu bar.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I've tried Mondomouse... The app (similar to clicking and dragging the title bar) couldn't move the window above the system menu bar.

Comment: I've also tried BetterTouchTool. Similarly, cannot move the window above the system menu bar.

Comment: Can't you just press Enter to press that button? You might need to enable access to all items with `⌃F7`.

Comment: The enter button works on Windows but not on Mac. Big frustration for me.

Comment: I was able to get past one of the errors by rotating the display 90 degrees with the vertical as 1080p there was space for the error message. However, a new message popped up that was even taller. This is getting ridiculous.

Comment: Weird… The Enter button should always work, you might need to `Tab` to it, or enable access to all window controls. If a window has focus, you can always dismiss it. Try running `alert();` from a Javascript console to try.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to press enter to continue. I know usually when a error message pops up with continue or cancel buttons usually the continue button is already selected by default. Click on the window and press enter and you should be good.

I really wish apple would implement a Alt+click option like Ubuntu. With Ubuntu you can alt+click anywhere on the window to drag and move it. Really great feature that perfect for situations like this.

Comment: Alt-click (or similar) is available with the tools I mentioned in the comments (BetterTouchTool and Mondomouse)... They move the windows, but not beyond the system menu bar.

Comment: Thanks Joshua! This will do the trick perfectly. Now only if Apple would add these featurse in the OS.